# Hangfire Load Balance between Servers

Tags: hangfire

I have 3 Hangfire servers that all are connected to the same database. Once nightly I have a Recurring job that will trigger multiple Enqueued jobs.

For example I have server A,B, and C, at 10 pm my Recurring job runs on server A and it Enqueues 15 Background Jobs. However, all 15 jobs will process on server A. I want there to be 5 jobs on A, 5 on B and 5 on C.

Is it possible to balance the load like this?

Answer (score 0):

Besides limiting the number of workers to 5 on each server, the first available worker will continue to pick up the job. The QueuePollInterval also plays a part in this. If the polling time is longer than you'll have jobs picked by one server's workers. Making it too small might cause excessive reads on db as well (beware).

BUT, as long as you have no resource contention, you should let the servers continue to run with current behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; however, it does seem that multiple jobs on the same server fight for resources. My solution was to use the hangfire Queuing system, when a hangfire server is deployed it looks at two queues 1 the default and another that has the same name as the server, just some GUID. Then before I schedule I job I check the status of each queue and assign the job to the queue with the least jobs.